# Make hairs thicker in viewport

Tags: hair

Is it possible to make hairs ((thicker)) in viewport without adding more hairs to the particle system.......Using (line with) setting in user preferences panel gives desired look to the hairs but also adds thickness to all UI Is it possible to add thickness to the hairs and not the whole UI.. [image]